# What does "invalid procedure call" mean in IIS 7 with asp application and how to fix it?

Tags: iis-7, web-server

What does "invalid procedure call" mean in IIS 7 with asp application and how to fix it?

Comment: "Classic" asp, not asp.net, right?

Comment: Yep, that's right! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this article which explains some possible reasons:

[Why do I get 'Invalid procedure call or argument'?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/files/directories-fso/why-do-i-get-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument.html)

> This often happens because you used a
>   VBScript "friendly name" constant in
>   place of its integer equivalent.
>   Visual Basic understands these
>   friendly names, such as
>   FileSystemObject's 'forAppending' and
>   'forWriting' constants.

or

> Another possible cause is trying to
>   use a string operation (like Mid(),
>   InStr(), Left() or Right()) on a NULL
>   value.

or

> Another possibility is that you are
>   coming over from JavaScript, or
>   otherwise think that string lengths
>   are 0-based.

or

> Still one more possibility is that you have unexpected characters in an FSO writeline call.

---

This Microsoft Support article could also be helpful:

["Invalid Procedure Call" Error Message or Access Violation When You Try to Assign User-Defined Type to Variant](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;326345)

> When you assign a user-defined type to
>   a Variant in a multithreaded
>   environment (for example, in Microsoft
>   COM+ or in Microsoft Internet
>   Information Server [IIS]), you may
>   receive an "Invalid Procedure Call"
>   error message or an access violation
>   (0xC0000005) in MSVBVM60.dll.